# Dynamic combine of reducers

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a dashboard with widgets and they depend on the current user. So we don't know which all widgets are going to load at compile time. That said , the state will also have dynamic fields for these widgets.I have a reducer for each widget. How do i combine all the reducers of required widgets ?

My state may look like :

```
{ dashboardId: 12,
  widgetList:{

      w1: {
          widgetTitle:'widget 1'
          data:[]
       },
       w2:{
          widgetTitle:'widget 2'
          data:[]

       }   
  }
}
```

Now i want to combine Reducers:

```
combineReducers({
  w1:widget1Reducer,
  w2:widget2Reducer
})
```

Now, the issue is we dont know which all widgets are going to load for the current dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to combine multiple reducers using the helper. Create a `widgetList` reducer that will update to specified widget using the appropriate widget reducer:

```js
function widgetList(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case WIDGET_A_FOO:
    case WIDGET_A_BAR:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.id]: widgetA(state[action.id], action),
      }

    case WIDGET_B_BAZ:
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.id]: widgetB(state[action.id], action),
      }

    case DELETE_WIDGET:
      return _.omit(state, action.id)

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

In the above example, `action.id` holds the widget ID. `widgetA` and `widgetB` are the reducers of widget A and widget B.

Comment: Thanks, that was neat :)

Comment: The only downside i see about this is we may end up importing  reducers for all the widgets  ( ~ say 100) . i'm using webpack, is there any way i download only required reducers for the current page?